# Not able to re-use threads in perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, queue

I am tailing a file, reading each line and feeding it to thread queue, using the below code

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;

use Thread::Queue;

use threads 'exit' => 'threads_only';

$thread_limit = 10;

my $q   = Thread::Queue->new();

my @thr = map {
    threads->create(
        sub {
            while ( defined( my $item = dequeue( $q ) ) ) {
                test( $item );
            }
        } );
} 1 .. $thread_limit;

my $file = File::Tail->new( "/path/File.txt" );

while ( defined( my $line = $file->read ) ) {

    my @j;
    if ( $line !~ /\s/ ) {
        push( @j, $line );
    }
    else {
        my @temp = split( /\s/, $line );
        my $size = @temp;
        for ( my $i = 0 ; $i <= $size ; $i++ ) {
            push( @j, $temp[$i] );
        }
    }

    {
        lock( $q );
        $q->enqueue( @job );
    }
}
```

Problem:

thread_limit = 10

now, once it reaches "number of active threads" = 1, threads stop, though the queue has more work items to dequeue. Can you please help?
Reading file for work items will be continuous.

Comment: $q->enqueue(@job); is $q->enqueue(@j);

Comment: You ***must always*** `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program, ans declare all of your variables with `my` as close as possible to their first point of use

Comment: The whole of your `if` statement (if you used `' '` instead of `/\s/` as you should) is the same as `my @j = split ' ', $line`. And you must pass an array by reference to `enqueue` so you must write `$q->enqueue(\@j)`

Comment: Re "now, once it reaches "number of active threads" = 1, threads stop" Well, yeah. If you end your workers, you won't have any workers. So why do you end your workers?

Comment: `strict` and warnings are doubly important for threading programs. Anything parallel gives you a whole new class of fruity and exciting bugs as the execution sequence of your program becomes less well defined. But it really is something you should be doing _before_ asking for assistance with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the threads in your program dies with `Undefined subroutine &main::dequeue` and the main program dies with `Can't locate object method "new" via package "File::Tail"`.

- Add `use File::Tail;`.
- Change `dequeue( $q )` to `$q->dequeue()`.

Adding `use strict; use warnings;` (which you should *always* use) finds problems.

- Change `$q->enqueue( @job );` to `$q->enqueue( @j );`.

Still more problems are revealed as you fix the above.

- Remove `lock( $q );`. 1) It's won't work since it's not a shared variable, 2) Locking in only one place is useless, and 3) Thread::Queue is thread-safe.
- Subroutine `test` doesn't exist.

After applying those fixes and some other cleanup, you get the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use File::Tail         qw( );
use Thread::Queue 3.01 qw( );

use constant NUM_WORKERS      => 10;
use constant COMMAND_FILE_QFN => '...';
use constant DEBUG            => 1;

sub worker {
    my ( $job ) = @_;
    print( "Processed $job.\n" );
}

my $q = Thread::Queue->new();
for (1..NUM_WORKERS) {
    async {
        while ( defined( my $job = $q->dequeue() ) ) {
            worker( $job );
        }
    };
}

my $tail = File::Tail->new(
    name        => COMMAND_FILE_QFN,
    maxinterval => DEBUG ? 1 : 60,
);
while ( defined( my $line = $tail->read() ) ) {
    $q->enqueue( split( ' ', $line ) );
}

$q->end();
$_->join() for threads->list();
```

Comment: I think Thread::Queue's can be locked - the modules suggest doing so if you're going to do non-atomic stuff to it. It's irrelevant in this case, but it can be done.

Comment: @Sobrique, I wouldn't lock the T::Q object itself (`lock %$q;`, which is the first thing `enqueue` and `dequeue` do). Not sure what this has to do with my answer (or the question).