# Perl multithreading slower when memory usage getting high

Tags: multithreading, perl, memory

Hi all~ I has written a very simple code in Perl using multithreading. The codes are as follows.

```
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use threads;
use Benchmark qw(:hireswallclock);

my $starttime;
my $finishtime;
my $timespent;
my $num_of_threads = 1;
my $total_size = 10000000;
my $chunk_size = int($total_size / $num_of_threads);

if($total_size % $num_of_threads){
        $chunk_size++;
}

my @threads = ();

$starttime = Benchmark->new;

for(my $i = 0; $i < $num_of_threads; $i++) {
        my $thread = threads->new(\&search);
        push (@threads, $thread);
}

foreach my $thread (@threads) {
        $thread->join();
}

my $finishtime = Benchmark->new;
$timespent = timediff($finishtime, $starttime);
print "$num_of_threads threads used in ".timestr($timespent)."\nDone!\n";

sub search{
        my $i = 0;
        while($i < $chunk_size){
            $i++;
        }

        return 1;
}
```

This piece of codes works fine as when increasing the number of threads, it will run faster.

However, when adding additional lines in the middle, which will create an array in big size, the code will run more slowly when adding more threads. The codes with the additional lines are shown below.

```
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use threads;
use Benchmark qw(:hireswallclock);

my $starttime;
my $finishtime;
my $timespent;
my $num_of_threads = 1;
my $total_size = 10000000;
my $chunk_size = int($total_size / $num_of_threads);

if($total_size % $num_of_threads){
        $chunk_size++;
}

##########Additional codes##########
print "Preparing data...\n";
$starttime = Benchmark->new;

my @array = ();

for(my $i = 0; $i < $total_size; $i++){
        my $rn = rand();
        push(@array, $rn);
}

$finishtime = Benchmark->new;
$timespent = timediff($finishtime, $starttime);
print "Used ".timestr($timespent)."\n";
######################################

my @threads = ();

$starttime = Benchmark->new;

for(my $i = 0; $i < $num_of_threads; $i++) {
        my $thread = threads->new(\&search);
        push (@threads, $thread);
}

foreach my $thread (@threads) {
        $thread->join();
}

my $finishtime = Benchmark->new;
$timespent = timediff($finishtime, $starttime);
print "$num_of_threads threads used in ".timestr($timespent)."\nDone!\n";

sub search{
        my $i = 0;
        while($i < $chunk_size){
            $i++;
        }

        return 1;
}
```

I am so confused regarding such a behaviour in Perl's multithreading. Does anyone has any idea what may go wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have time to look in details, but each thread makes a copy of `@array` (and of any other variable that is not declared as shared), and I'm guessing this is the slow part. Use [`threads::shared`](https://perldoc.perl.org/threads::shared) and declare `@array` as `:shared`; this should improve performance.

Comment: Thanks @Dada! It does work for the codes above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remember that when using ithreads - interpreter threads - the entire Perl interpreter, including code and memory, is cloned into the new thread.  So the more data to be cloned, the longer it takes.  There are ways to control what is cloned; take a look at the `threads` perldoc.

You should do as little as possible and not even load many modules until after you have spawned your threads.

If you do have a lot of data that will be used by all the threads, make it shared with `threads::shared`.  Then to share a data structure use `shared_clone()`.  You cannot simply `share()` anything, other than a simple variable.  That shared variable can only contain plain scalars or other shared references.

If you are going to consume or pump that data, make it a queue instead with the `Thread::Queue` module.  It automatically shares the values and takes care of the locking.  After spawning your pool of worker threads, control them with `Thread::Semaphore`.  That way they won't terminate before you've given them anything to do.  You can also prevent race conditions.

https://metacpan.org/pod/threads::shared

HTH

Comment: 1) you can `share()` a scalar, an array or a hash. 2) if you use `Thread::Queue`, you probably don't need `Thread::Semaphore` to prevent the threads from terminating: use `while (defined(my $item = $queue->dequeue))` in the threads, and they won't terminate until you do `$queue->end`.

Comment: There are other non-queue activities you might want to regulate with a semaphore.  Of course, TIMTOWTDI.

Comment: Thanks @lordadmira for pointing to the share issue. It indeed works in a small scale, such as in the codes above. I am also reading the documentation but it may take some time for me to fully understand the mechanisms. What if I have a more complex script, with quite some larger hashes and arrays, and I would like to implement multithreading in only one subroutine, shall I make all of thoe big variables as shared?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962459/589924) for a Thread::Queue example. There's also similar Thread::Queue::Any with automatically serializes queued valued so they don't need to be shared.

Comment: @seallin Re "*What if I have a more complex script*", You can pass references to shared arrays/hashes around just as if they weren't shared

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for pointing me to the relative directions! I have learned and tried different things, inlucding how to use shared and queue, which should be able to solve the problem. So I revised the script as follows:

```
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Thread::Queue;
use Benchmark qw(:hireswallclock);

my $starttime;
my $finishtime;
my $timespent;
my $num_of_threads = shift @ARGV;
my $total_size = 100000;
######Initiation of a 2D queue######
print "Preparing queue...\n";
$starttime = Benchmark->new;
my $queue = Thread::Queue->new();
for(my $i = 0; $i < $total_size; $i++){
        my $rn1 = rand();
        my $rn2 = rand();
        my @interval :shared = sort($rn1, $rn2);
        $queue->enqueue(\@interval);
}
$finishtime = Benchmark->new;
$timespent = timediff($finishtime, $starttime);
print "Used ".timestr($timespent)."\n";
#####################################
$starttime = Benchmark->new;
my $queue_copy = $queue; #Copy the 2D queue so that the original queue can be kept\
for(my $i = 0; $i < $num_of_threads; $i++) {
        my $thread = threads->create(\&search, $queue_copy);
}
foreach my $thread (threads->list()) {
        $thread->join();
}
$finishtime = Benchmark->new;
$timespent = timediff($finishtime, $starttime);
print "$num_of_threads threads used in ".timestr($timespent)."\nDone!\n";
#####################################
sub search{
        my $temp_queue = $_[0];
        while(my $temp_interval = $temp_queue->dequeue_nb()){
                #Do something
        }
        return 1;
}
```

What I was trying to do was , first, to make a queue of arrays, with each containing two numbers. A copy of the queue was made as I want to preserve the original queue when going through it. Then the copied queue was gone through using multithreads. However, I still found out that it ran slower when more threads were added, which I have no clue why.

Comment: You have discovered the law of diminishing returns.  Remember that threads are a way to use *spare* system resources that are not being used by any line of execution.  More threads only correlate to more performance up to the point that all of that spare resource is utilized.  Whether it is CPU time or network time or whatever.  e.g. You have 4 CPU cores so you spawn 4 worker threads that are able to max out the 4 CPU cores.  Adding more threads will slow down the overall workflow because more CPU time must be diverted from work to manage the thread scheduling.

Comment: Thanks @lordadmira! This is an interesting fact to know as I did not pay much attention to the threading issue before. Does it mean that it will shorten the time to run the entire work flow only when multithreading is used in a proper way? For example, a big job can be split as early as possible and the small ones can be run simutaneously, in a way that less CPU time is needed to manage the multiple processes?

Comment: There are a few issues with your code that explain the performance you're observing (and "law of diminishing returns" is far from the main one). `@interval` does not have to be shared. `my $queue_copy = $queue;` does not copy the queue. The utilization of your queue is somewhat exotic. What you probably should do is 1) create the queue 2) create the threads (which should do `while (defined(my $interval = $queue->dequeue))` rather than `$dequeue_nb`) 3) fill the queue 4) wait for the threads to end.

Comment: Still, the main issue IMO is that the main loop of  the threads (in the sub `search`) is empty, and thus, the execution time is dominated by things like creating threads, fetching items from the queue, managing threads... Use a real example there, and you should see some changes.

Comment: (lordadmira's point that it's pointless to use more than 4 threads if you have only 4 logical cores on your CPU is true though)

Comment: Consider the following one-liner: `time perl -Mthreads -MThread::Queue -e '$q = Thread::Queue->new; threads->create(\&search) for 1 .. shift; $q->enqueue($_) for 1 .. 10000; $q->end; $_->join for threads->list; sub search { while (defined$q->dequeue) { $x = 0; $x ++ while $x < 100000 } }' 1`. Change the last digit to select the number of threads to use. (add some newlines if you have trouble understanding the code) On my computer, it runs in 24 sec with 1 thread, 12 sec with 2 threads, 8.5 sec with 3 threads and 7 sec with 4 threads.

Comment: In that case, the "job" I am parallelizing is `$x = 0; $x ++ while $x < 100000`, which is quite expensive. If it were only "nothing" (like in your example), multithreading would probably not improve performance. Some thing to consider: Is the execution time dominated by generating your dataset to mutlithread (ie, filling the queue)? If yes, you should try to multithread _that_.